# Need advice on improving JSON structure

Tags: json, configuration

I'm creating a JSON configurations for my application (C#/.NET Core). I use Newtonsoft.Json to work with JSON files. The app works with external devices that connect to the host machine either wired or wirelessly. I call this equipment under test (EUT).

I have one JSON file that stores the configurations for the EUTs, mainly their capabilities and how those capabilities are performed. The structure is as follow:

```
{
    "Eut": [
        {
            "Name": "",
            "SharedConfig": { }
            "Capabilities": [
                {
                    "Name": "",
                    "Method": "",
                    "Configs": { }
                },
                // More capabilities here
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are the meanings of each "Eut" entry:

- Name: name of the EUT
- SharedConfig: contains the configurations that some capabilities may share. For example, if the EUT is connected wiredly, the shared config could include an endpoint: "Endpoint": { "Ip": "", "Port": 1234 }. This object does not have a concrete structure
- Capabilities: capabilities that an EUT can perform. An entry for this does not have a concrete struture

  - "Name": an identifier for a specific capability (e.g.: "TemperatureSensor" measures the temperature, "VideoStream" fetches the stream from EUT's display and sends it somewhere,...)
  - "Method": the method/strategy to perform the capability
  - "Configs": contains configurations that are specific for a certain capability and a certain method. Also, there can be a "References" array that contains reference configurations that are in "SharedConfig" or a different JSON file even. As I mentioned before, the objects declared in "SharedConfig" could be used by some capabilities. I'm not sure if doing references like this is a good idea. I have to invent a domain specific language to parse these references.

I'm thinking that the "References" can be improved to be less complex to work with in code. But please let me know if there are other improvements that can be made. Thank you!